# Android Editext having issue with backspace key

Tags: android, android-edittext, backspace

I have an `AlertDialog` in which I am setting a `XML` as its view. In that `xml layout` I have an `EditText`. But after entering data in `EditText`, if I am trying to delete using backspace, the characters are not getting deleted (its like backspace is not working).

Am I missing something? I searched but did not get any proper solution except adding keylistener. I think it should work simple?

Anyone there to help me.

Here is my `EditText`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/TextBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text">
        <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Dialog ceation code:

```
hintDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    .setTitle("Enter Your Hint:")
    .setView(hintDialogView).create();
    hintDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        hintDialog.dismiss();
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: please paste the code of `AlertDialog` creation portion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have any onKeyListeners set? This can be the cause of the problem.

try this:

```
 hintDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
.setTitle("Enter Your Hint:")
.setView(hintDialogView).create();
hintDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    hintDialog.dismiss();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

(adding the return false;)

Comment: You are my time saver... More than 3 hours searching for this exact fix..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK listener?
Called to process key events. You can override this to intercept all key events before they are dispatched to the window. Be sure to call this implementation for key events that should be handled normally.
when you override dispatchKeyEvent method,u must call super.dispatchKeyEvent(event) when return.

Answer (score 0):

Should not KEYCODE_BACK but KEYCODE_DEL instead. It works for sure in your case.